# Sorting and flattening an integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have a project for an intro java class where we have to create a game that a user selects the number of players, rounds, and dice to be used. When the dice are rolled they are supposed to be sorted from largest to smallest. The problem I'm having is turning the sorted array into an int value (i.e. 4, 3, 2 into 432). Is there a way just to combine the array or do I have to create a loop? Thanks for the help and I hope this is clear enough because my brain is shot.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * @param args
 */

class beatThat {


   public static void main(String[] args) {  
       int players = 0, rounds, dice, size, dValue, roundScore, a, b, t = 0;

       Scanner playerInput;
       playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);

       //   Thanks the user for playing the game.
       //   Asks for number of players.
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing Beat That!");

       //   Picks number of players.            
       //   If number of players not correct, requests selection again.
       do {
           System.out.println("Please pick your number of players (2-4):");
           players = playerInput.nextInt();

       } while (players < 2 | players > 4);

       //   Picks number of rounds.         
       //   If number of rounds not correct, requests selection again.
       do {
           System.out.println("Please pick your number of rounds " + 
                "(max 15):");
           rounds = playerInput.nextInt();

       } while (rounds < 1 | rounds > 15);

       //   Picks number of dice.           
       //   If number of dice not correct, requests selection again.            
       do {
           System.out.println("Please pick your number of dice (max 7):");
           dice = playerInput.nextInt();
       } while (dice < 1 | dice > 7);

       // Creates one dimensional array to hold dice values
       int score [] = new int [dice];

       // Generates random value between 1 & 6 for the amount of dice
       // chosen and assigns them to the array.
       for (int d = 0; d < dice; d++) {
           dValue = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
           System.out.print(dValue + ", ");
           score [d] = dValue;
       }

       // Rearranges array from largest number to smallest number.  
       for (a=1; a < dice; a++) {
           for (b = dice-1; b >= a; b--) {
               if(score[b-1] < score[b]){
                   t = score[b-1];
                   score[b-1] = score[b];
                   score[b] = t;

               }
           }
       }

       //////       // Can Delete. Prints out sorted array
       System.out.println();    
       System.out.println("Sorted array is: ");
       for (int i = 0; i < dice; i++)
           System.out.print(score[i] + " ");
       System.out.println("\n");

       // Makes sorted array into one score.
       int arrayLength = score.length;
       int arrayIndex; 
       for (int i = 0; i < dice; i++) {
           arrayIndex = (arrayLength - i - 1);
           roundScore = score[i];
           System.out.print("Your roundScore: ");
           System.out.println(roundScore);  
       }

       ///////      End of Dice method              


   }

}
```

Comment: You should probably be using `||` for an OR instead of `|`.

Comment: Yes, a loop is the simplest/fastest way of doing it.

Comment: you simply need to use `roundScore += score[i]; roundScore *= 10;` in the last loop

Comment: or `roundScore = roundScore * 10 + score[i];`

Comment: @njzk2 You want the other order as multiply by 10 last will leave a 0 at the end.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: agreed, edited my answer according to that. much neater way to get rid of the last `0` indeed.

Comment: BTW Arrays.sort(score) will also sort the dice. You can then print/generate the number in reverse order to appear reverse sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply multiply the dice by the base at each round:

```
int roundScore = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dice; i++) {
       roundScore = roundScore * 10 + score[i];
}
System.out.println(roundScore);
```

In your example, `{4, 3, 2}` gives a score of `432`, with the intermediate values: `0, 4, 43, 432`

### edit

Rephrased according to @PeterLawrey's suggestion

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot for that. I was thinking I would have to use another array while using exponents to get the values for each element, then add it all together. I forgot the first rule in pretty much anything which is to keep it simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Store it first in a string, then convert it back to number

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

String number = "";
for(int i=0; i<nums.length;i++)
   number+=nums[i];

int finalNum = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/xVPMer)

Comment: this is quite ugly... concatenating strings just to avoid a trivial multiplication.

Comment: If you're going to use the `String` route then why not use `StringBuilder`?

Comment: A downvote is made for incorrect answer. If you believe there's better answer, you are free to post it :)

Comment: @Amir: not incorrect, `not useful` according to the tooltip over the button. I think this is the worst possible way. of achieving the result.

Comment: @njzk2 I disagree.  It is useful.  However, not efficient or the best way.

Comment: @Amir Something requiring more instruction doesn't make it worse.

Comment: Yup I know but I don't think that his solution is more efficient. He need to learn how to respect people answers

Comment: @Amir: your solution is `O(n^2)` because concatenating 2 strings is directly proportional to the length of the sum of the strings. my solution is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is probably a good way.  Check out [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
public static int intArrayToInt(int[] arr){
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        ret.append(arr[i]);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(ret.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, it is the best way. If you are really particular about performance, use a StringBuffer to concatenate and then convert to integer.

However, if you just want a one line solution (not worried about performance), then to convert an array of integers into a single integer, use this:

```
Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll(",|\\s|\\[|\\]", ""))
```

Comment: I don't think `Arrays.toString` do what you think it does. The docs reads `The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", "`. For this example, something like `[4, 3, 2]`, which obviously cannot be passed to `parseInt`

Comment: Ohh, I think I must have been doing something else when I wrote it :)  See the update answer now. That's what I intended to write. Thanks for the catch.